# Get closest previous date T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I need to get select the closest previous date to a date parameter. Currently I am selecting the closest either side of the date using this code:

```
SELECT TOP 1 equities, fund, e_date
        FROM tbl_assetmix
        WHERE fund = @fund_code
        ORDER BY ABS(DateDiff(dd, e_date, @statementdate)) asc
```

I know it is really simple but can someone suggest how I would be able to select the closest date prior to the @statementdate parameter?

Thanks,
Tristan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select just lines where date is prior to @statementdate:

```
SELECT TOP 1 equities, fund, e_date
FROM tbl_assetmix
WHERE fund = @fund_code
AND e_date < @statementdate
ORDER BY ABS(DateDiff(dd, e_date, @statementdate)) asc
```

or replace the

```
AND e_date < @statementdate
```

with

```
AND e_date <= @statementdate
```

if the same day is allowed.

Comment: You don't need to use DateDiff, you can order by date and take the most recent one.